# How does FileReader class exactly works with unicode text file

Tags: java, unicode

As far as I know `FileReader` class is used to read characters and Java uses Unicode format so it should read 2 byte with each `.read()` method means 1 character at time for a text file saved with Unicode format. But my code below is printing space before each character.

```
import java.io.*;
class pro1{
static int t; 
 public static void main(String argsp[]){ 
  try{
  File f=new File("note.txt");
  FileReader g=new FileReader(f);     
  while((t=g.read())!=-1){ 

  char b=(char)t;
  System.out.println("lets see what happens: "+b);

                            }
   }
    catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("message: "+e);
   }       
                    }                                                   
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Unicode is not a character encoding by itself. Your text file has an actual encoding, and if you want to read it properly you need to know which it is.

Comment: *"But my code below is printing space before each character."* -  You call that "code"?  I call it a dogs breakfast!  Did your teacher not tell you about INDENTATION?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...and java uses unicode format so it should read 2 byte with each .read() method...

Unicode is not a 2-byte format. Indeed, as Biffen says, it's not a character encoding at all. There are [several Unicode character encodings](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html): A mostly-single-byte one called UTF-8 *(but some characters will be 2, 3, or 4 bytes)*, a mostly-two-byte one called UTF-16 *(but some characters will be four)*, and an always-four-byte one called UTF-32. There are also variations of these. Obligatory link: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

When you create a `FileReader` the way you have, it uses the default encoding for your platform, which is likely to be Windows-1252, ISO 8859-1, or UTF-8. To specify the format, you can use an `InputStreamReader` [constructed with](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.charset.Charset-) a specific encoding.